# Angular text interpolation not displaying text

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't see any errors in my Angular code, but when I use the developer tools, the username doesn't appear due to text interpolation errors.you know the answer?

Useraccount.ts :

```
export class Useraccount {
   id:string = '';
   username: string = '';
   name:string = '';
   password:string =' ';
   email:string = ''; 
}
```

---

Header.ts :

```
user= this.authservice.useraccountValue;

constructor(private authservice:AuthService) { 

  //set user
  this.authservice.user.subscribe(x => this.user = x);

  console.log(this.user); 
}
```

Header.html :

```html
<ul class="info_ul">

  <li>{{ user.username }}</li>
  <li><a (click)="logout($event)">logout</a></li>

</ul>
```

UseraccountSubject assigned to authservice.ts and BhaviorSubject Service

```
export class AuthService { 

    private useraccountSubject:BehaviorSubject<Useraccount>;
    public user: Observable<Useraccount>;
    
    constructor(private http:HttpClient, private router:Router) {
        
        this.useraccountSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Useraccount>(null as any); 
        
        this.user = this.useraccountSubject.asObservable();
        
        if(sessionStorage.getItem("USER")) { 

            const user =sessionStorage.getItem("USER");

            if(user){
                this.useraccountSubject.next(JSON.parse(user)); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    
    private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) { 

        if (err.status === 200) {
            console.error('Error:',err.error.data) 
        } else { 
            console.error(`Backend error ${err.status}`) 
        } 
        
        return throwError('Try again') 
    } 
    
    private handleErrorsingup(err: HttpErrorResponse) { 

        if (err.status === 201) {
            console.error('Error:',err.error.data) 
        } else { 
            alert('faild');
            console.error(`Backend error ${err.status}`) 
        } 

        return throwError('Try again.') 
    } 
    
    login(username:string,password:string) { 

        const params = new FormData();
        params.append('username', username); 
        params.append('password', password);
        
        return this.http.post<any>
        (`${baseUrl}/signin/`, params, {observe:'response', withCredentials: true})
        .pipe(
            map(user=> { 
                tap(user => { 
                    this.useraccountSubject.next((user)); 
                })
                catchError(this.handleError) 
            
                sessionStorage.setItem("USER", JSON.stringify(user));  

                return user; 
            })
        ) 
    }
        
    signup(email:string,password:string,name:string ){
        const params = new FormData();
        params.append('email', email);
        params.append('password', password);
        params.append('name', name);
        
        return this.http.post<any>
            (`${baseUrl}/signup/`, params, {observe:'response', withCredentials:true}
            )
            .pipe( 
                catchError(this.handleErrorsingup) 
            )
    }
    
    logout() { 
        return this.http.post<any>
            (`${baseUrl}/signout/`, {})
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.useraccountSubject.next(null as any);
                
                sessionStorage.clear();
                
                this.router.navigate(['login']) 
            } 
            ) 
    } 
    public get useraccountValue():Useraccount { 
        return this.useraccountSubject.value; 
    } 
}
```

> Error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null(reading 'username')

error after adding :

> Error: src/app/auth-service.ts:59:36 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Useraccount'.

> this.useraccountSubject.next((user));
> ~~~~~
> × Failed to compile.

Comment: Do you have User details available in sessionStorage? Can you add a `console.log(user)` within `if(user){...}` block and check if it gets logged. If yes, then what is the structure of the user data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I can see that user in useraccountSubject in Constructure of class, and its call once when you create instance. I think you have to set the value to useraccountSubject when you got the user object in login API.

You can follow this [example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/08/06/angular-8-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example)

You can try below code, otherwise create sample project in stackbliz

````
    const params = new FormData();
    params.append('username', username);
    params.append('password', password);
    return this.http.post<any>(`${baseUrl}/signin/`, params, {observe:'response', 
    withCredentials: true})//withCredentials:true
   .pipe(map(user=>{
     // Try to set After getting response from login
    tap(user => {this.useraccountSubject.next((user));})
    catchError(this.handleError)
     sessionStorage.setItem("USER", JSON.stringify(user));
     return user;
     }))
  }```
````

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want a more clear answer.

Comment: If you create a sample code  in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gcrbuf then I can help you

Comment: @bxeom I have updated answer you can try it

Comment: Shall I write my code there? @Jitendra

Comment: I'm at home right now. I will try to answer the questions you updated tomorrow. Thank you so much for letting me know until the end.

Comment: I did the way you told me but 
An argument of type 'unknown' cannot be assigned to a parameter of type 'user account'.

Comment: I added  this.useraccount.next(user) then Error An argument of type 'HttpResponse<any>' is not allowed against a balance of 'Useraccount'.

Comment: i need your help @jitendra

Comment: @bxeom You can ask question here

Comment: Chat is not yet available. Updated my problem code

Comment: this.useraccountSubject.next(user as Useraccount); 
 You can try this

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user">
<li>{{user.username}}</li>
</ng-container>

user:any= this.authservice.useraccountValue;
```

Comment: It was a good alternative, but it didn't work